# Load different gallery slider depending on item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have three box items in my gallery (the gallery will eventually grow), each item when clicked must open a popup gallery slider with it's images in it. So it would be three different sliders, maybe more in the future.

How can I difference **each box gallery from the others?** so when clicked it just an independent gallery and not all images?

**This is my markup:**

```
    <a class="box small" onclick="openslider()" href="javascript:void(0)">
        <img src="/1.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
        <h5>Title 1</h5>
        <p>Description 1</p>
    </a>

    <a class="box small" onclick="openslider()" href="javascript:void(0)">
        <img src="/2.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
        <h5>Title 2</h5>
        <p>Description 2</p>
    </a>

    <a class="box small" onclick="openslider()" href="javascript:void(0)">
        <img src="/3.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
        <h5>Title 3</h5>
        <p>Description 3</p>
    </a>
```

**The JS:**

```
function openslider(){
    $('.modal_container').fadeIn();
}
```

**The slider markup:**

```
<div class="slider_box gallery1">
    <div class="slider">
        <img src="/img/slider.jpg" alt="slider" width="587" height="414" />
        <img src="/img/slider2.jpg" alt="slider2" width="800" height="564" />
        <img src="/img/slider3.jpg" alt="slider3" width="587" height="414" />
        <img src="/img/slider4.jpg" alt="slider4" width="800" height="564" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: openslider(this) as a good start

Answer (score 0):

Change your HTML like

```
<a id="gallery1" class="box small" onclick="openslider(event, this)" href="javascript:void(0)">
        <img src="/3.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
        <h5>Title 3</h5>
        <p>Description 3</p>
    </a>
```

So that when openSlider gets called, it takes the obj reference in obj
Then change your JS code like

```
function openslider(event, obj){
  if($(obj).attr(id) == "gallery1")
    $('.modal_container').fadeIn();
  if($(obj).attr(id) == "gallery2")
    $('.the_other_modal_container').fadeIn();
}
```

so you can make selection based on id's you have in the `<a>` anchor tags

EDIT:

In case you have a lot of galleries i.e. a lot of IF conditions, you can simple select an ID scheme like

```
<a id="box_1" ...>
```

and then select the numeric part and use it in your .model_container

```
 function openslider(event, obj){
   var id = $(obj).attr(id).split("_")[1];
   $('#gallery_'+'id).fadeIn();
  }
```

So, in short, give ids to your anchor tags and your galleries in this scheme

```
<a id="box_1">
<div id="gallery_1">

<a id="box_2">
<div id="gallery_2">

...
```

and so on

Comment: Thanks, but what if the gallery grow up to 10 box items?